# Problems with running atom editor via terminal

Tags: command-line, 16.04, atom

Recently, within the last day or so my ubuntu 16 system has been having trouble with running atom from the terminal. When I just click-launch the application I don't have any problems, but the system doesn't seem to be responding when I try to run `sudo atom /blah/file/blah.html` Not only does the system not seem to be responding, but the system seems to be chocking on the the command as the system shuts itself off (I think the processor is over heating). Not sure why this is happening, or how to diagnose it. Any advice?

Update: I seem to be running an older version of atom, so that maybe an issue. It is

```
Atom    : 1.12.1
Electron: 1.3.6
Chrome  : 52.0.2743.82
Node    : 6.3.0
```

Comment: I only had a few packages, and I unstalled them. It doesn't seem to be changing anything...

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` with `atom`?

Comment: So, unless I'm totally wrong, without elevated privileges I can't edit files on my dev server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem, but when starting atom in general. I think it may be caused by https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/13084

A temporary workaround which works for me is [this script on Atom's GitHub page](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/13084#issuecomment-260205557)

```bsh
#! /bin/bash

ATOM_DISABLE_SHELLING_OUT_FOR_ENVIRONMENT=true /usr/bin/atom "$@" &

## wait a few secs, then kill all env collecting processes
sleep 3
PIDS=`ps aux | grep 'bash -ilc command env' | awk '{print $2}'`

for i in $PIDS
do
    kill -9 $i
    echo "killed: $i"
done
```